Delay-doppler analysis of channel resource grid
Suppose i have a 5G NR channel resource grid or perfect channel estimate(H_grid) with 14 OFDM symbols and 1272 subcarriers. Now, after taking 2D fft of H_grid, i want to estimate doppler and delay spread. What are the further post-processing steps required to derive these estimates? To start with, what are the cut-offs for the low pass filter applied on the output of 2D fft?

The H_grid is obtained by taking 14 FFT, right? What do you want to do with the second 2D FFT?
